identify this paranormal movie
A friend told me about a movie in which a man's wife dies which leads him to test paranormal activies in search for her. He then starts hearing unearthly sounds, growing stronger by time, until he couldn't bear it.
Finally, it is revealed that the sounds were actually helping him to keep him from hearing the real horrific sounds of actual ghost, which I think might be fatal to him. 
Movie is released somewhere around 2005. 

What wrong have I done to deserve a downvote?

Sounds like White Noise (2005)?
"Architect Jonathan Rivers (Michael Keaton) is happily married to author Anna (Chandra West), but tragedy strikes when she is killed in an accident. Deep in grief, Jonathan hears from Raymond Price (Ian McNeice), who claims that he has intercepted messages from Anna via electronic voice phenomena. Jonathan eventually comes to believe Raymond's claims, but, as he is drawn further into investigating the phenomenon, a sinister supernatural presence invades his life."
The 2005 fits, dead wife, paranormal research/noise, and the protection from sinister noises which endangered him.

I thought about the same movie. Didn't remember that the main actor was Michael Keaton. Need to watch it again.
